# How to round down 0.005 to 3 decimal max in C#

Tags: c#, .net, math, rounding

I try to round decimal values without success in C#.

I must round up to 0,005 to lower .With a return value of 3 numbers maximum after the comma.

I explain:

**46.60501**  should return =>  **46.605**

**46.09784**  should return =>  **46.095**

**46.60434**  should return =>  **46.600** (and not 46.605 because rounded down ! )

Actually i use that code in c# (check the comments for see what's wrong) :

```
//Send '46.60501' return me '46.605' => Success
double center_latitude_min_box = Math.Round( (Math.Round(latitude * 200, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 200),3);

//Send '7.09784' return me '7.1' ?!? => No Success, and why only return 1 number after the comma ?
double center_longitude_min_box = Math.Round((Math.Round(longitude * 200, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 200), 3);
```

but it's not working well :'(

If somebody can help me ,  I will be very grateful ! I start to become crazy now ^^

Comment: Sorry @P6345uk it's not same , i don't want 1.246 return 1.250 . But 1.245

Comment: That isnt rounding then

Comment: yes, a rounded bottom to 0,005

Comment: And from the sample data, the title should be: _How to round down 0.005 to 3 decimal max in C#_

Comment: sorry you are right, i update now the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could use is something like

```
var x  = 0;
if((latitude*100) - Math.Truncate((latitude*100)) >=0.5)
{
x = (Math.Truncate((latitude*100))/100)+0.005;
}
else
{
x = (Math.Truncate((latitude*100))/100);
}
```

EDIT ***** EDIT
Gustav's solution below is much better

> This can really be done directly in one line:
>
> x = Math.Floor(latitude * 200) / 200;

Comment: wrap that in a function and that gives you what you want

Answer (score 1):

This can really be done directly in one line:

```
x = Math.Floor(latitude * 200) / 200;
```

Comment: Oh, just noticed the link above - which confirms ...